# Why does chaining selectors in Protractor return false when using isPresent

Tags: jasmine, protractor, angular, ionic2

So I'm writing automation tests for Ionic 2/Angular 2 and I have DOM element that looks like this

```
<ion-segment-button class="segment-button segment-activated" role="button" tappable="" value="orders" aria-pressed="true">
```

and I've created a page object that looks like this:

```
ordersButton: element(by.css('[value="orders"]')),
```

and in my spec file my test step looks like so

```
expect((orders.header.ordersButton).element(by.css('.segment-activated')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

this returns false and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wait for the [presence of the element](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var button = orders.header.ordersButton;
var segmentActivated = button.element(by.css('.segment-activated'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(segmentActivated), 5000);

expect(segmentActivated.isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: I haven't gotten a chance to test this out yet, but I will let you know as soon as I'm back on that project.