# Protractor multiCapabilities doesn't support suite config?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm just starting to add parallel testing to my config file and I'm running into an issue that I'm having trouble discerning elsewhere if its possible or not from Protractor. My multiCapabilities set up looks like this at the moment:

```
multiCapabilities:[{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    name: 'chrome-tests',
    count: 1,
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 1,
    suites: {
        repeatable: 'example/example.spec.js'
    }
}, {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    name: 'ff-tests',
    count: 1,
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 1,
    suites: {
        repeatable: 'example/example.spec.js'
    }
}],
```

and it fails with an error message of:

```
Cannot read property 'repeatable' of undefined
```

Am I missing something or does multiCapability not support suites running in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`suites` can only be defined on the upper level in your config. They *cannot be capability-specific*.

Comment: thanks! moving it out did the trick! just for my own edification, is that a scope thing?

Comment: @modusAndrew it is just that `suites` are not supported on a capability level. Might be a missing feature. Consider creating an issue at the [protractor github issue tracker](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues). Thanks. Also, should I add anything to the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35946597/771848, did it help?